# From Event driven OO to Redux architecture

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, reactjs, redux

I have a structure that is pretty much OO and I am about to migrate to React/Redux due to event mess. 
I am curious what to do with current modules, I have objects that have schema like:

```
User {
  getName()
  getSurname()
  etc...
}
```

And there are lots of these, they were used as fasade/factories for raw json data as I used to pass json and manipulate it (mutable data)

Now how to solve this in redux?

I get to the part where I have an async action call, I recieve raw data from api and than what?
Should I pass 'complex' object with their getters/setters to state? Its said to be immutable so it doesnt seem well with redux recomendations.

Or maybe convert the class-like elements to accessors like:

```
function getName(rawJson) {
  return rawJson.name
}
function setName(rawJson, name) {
  return Object.assign({}, rawJson, {name})
}
```

parse it in action and return a rawJSON chunk from action to reducer and than stick it to the new state?

EDIT:

A simple pseudocode module for user:

```
function User(raw) {
  return {
    getName: function() {
      return raw.name
    }
    setName: function(name) {
      raw.name = name
      return this
    }
  }
}
```

My point is about moving all data and flattening/normalizing it in store - would it be fine to have an array of e.g. User objects in store?  or should they all be pure json. I want to be sure its really only correct way to have all those objects turn into basic values cause it gonna be lots of work.

Comment: give an example of one of these facades.

Comment: question is not very clear as to what you need to accomplish and what's keeping that from happening...

Comment: edited, please check

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be totally relevant, but if I'm understanding your question and putting it another way: where to put business logic and other validations/manipulations:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1165

I personally follow this trend as well in that I put all of my async action manipulation in my action creators before storing them in a format of my choosing in the reducer.[image]

Here, I choose to convert to JSON whatever objects I get back from the API. Similarly you can do whatever logic you need here before dispatching a success request to store in your reducers.

Hope that helps/is relevant to whatever you were asking...

Comment: Ok, but what type of data do you return from action creator? I mean is the payload a JS object? Would it be acceptable to have an object in store(with methods, prototype etc)?
My point is that I need to send object back to server after user makes changes and press 'save' so it has to keep the same structure and properties as before and I am afraid that I will need to do a lot of conversion/parsing on the way from api to store and back to api....(in store we keep everything right, so some typical buisness data will be mixed with things like..should cookies info be displayed)